# Using OpenCV to correct stereo images

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d

I intend to make a program which will take stereo pair images, taken by a single camera, and then correct and crop them so that when the images are viewed side by side with the parallel or cross eye method, the best 3D effect will be achieved. The left image will be the reference image, the right image will be modified for corrections. I believe OpenCV will be the best software for these purposes. So far I believe the processing will occur something like this:

- Correct for rotation between images.
- Correct for y axis shift.

Doing so will I imagine result in irregular black borders above and below the right image so:

- Crop both images to the same height to remove borders.
- Compute stereo-correspondence/disparity
- Compute optimal disparity
- Correct images for optimal disparity

Okay, so that's my take on what needs doing and the order it occurs in, what I'm asking is, does that seem right, is there anything I've missed, anything in the wrong order etc. Also, which specific functions of OpenCV would I need to use for all the necessary steps to complete this project? Or is OpenCV not the way to go? Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is great for this.

There is a whole chapter in:

[image]

And all the sample code for this in the book ships with the opencv distribution

edit:     Roughly the steps are:

1. Remap each image to remove lens distortions and rotate/translate views to image center.
2. Crop pixels that don't appear in both views (optional)
3. Find matching objects in each view (stereoblock matching) create disparity map
4. Reproject disparity map into 3D model

Comment: I'm actually working my way through that book atm, but has anyone any comments on how my idea of the process looks? Amirite?